# How to change SignOutAsync ReturnUrl in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, authorization, logout

I am using .NET Core 2-3 with EF Identity cookie auth, and I need to be able to log any given user out of all browsing "sessions" they are logged in for.

To do this, I am "invalidating" the cookie with the following authorization filter:

```
public class CookieIsValidRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CookieIsValidRequirement>
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CookieIsValidRequirementHandler(
        ILogger<CookieIsValidRequirementHandler> logger,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
    ) {
        _logger = logger;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        CookieIsValidRequirement requirement)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Checking if cookie is valid...");

        Claim userIdClaim = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (userIdClaim == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userIdClaim.Value))
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"NameIdentifier Claim not found");
            context.Succeed(requirement); // This is needed to allow the home page to load
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (requirement.userIdsToLogOut.Contains(userIdClaim.Value))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Cookie is invalid! Logging user out!");
                await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                requirement.userIdsToLogOut.Remove(userIdClaim.Value);
                _logger.LogInformation($"CAN I USE THIS??? {_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext}");
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Cookie is valid!");
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is actually working pretty great, except that it redirects the user to:

```
https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FAccessDenied%3FReturnUrl%3D%252F
```

I like that it redirects them to the login page, but notice that the ReturnUrl is to an Access Denied page.  I don't want that.

I've tried looking into the black box here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore

And it looks like the auth model is tightly related to "schemes" that are "configured" using the small handful of options available in the startup class.

Comment: if you could peer into a black box, it is not a black box anymore :) I think you need to debug your code in your specific environment to find out what's wrong. Here's the source code for the signing out: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L364 - You can see how the redirect URL is built there. Try examining the possible values while debugging. If possible, you can even enable *Source Link* debugging to debug into the source code for better examining.

Comment: Just curious, how do you know where to go to get that blob link?  I can not seem to navigate through source code on GitHub that effectively.

Comment: you can track from the class which has the method/property you use. Here the `SignInManager`. Sometimes you need to guess the default implementations (because we just know the interfaces), the point here is to know the default logic. The github page is not very helpful to assist you to find what you need quickly, e.g: the `SignInManager` is searched with 6 pages of result, but the class is on the page 6 (sometimes there are up to more than 20 pages).

Comment: The framework team apply very good naming conventions, so it's fairly easy to guess the default implementation (e.g: almost like the interface name with `I` removed ***or*** with a prefix of `Default`). To find the exact implementation types, sometimes you need to read the code thoroughly so it will spend some time.

Comment: If downloading the source code and finding the classes using Visual Studio, then it would be much quicker (I've not tried this yet). Finally, to find the exact implementation types (at runtime), instead of reading the code you can debug it with support of *Source Link* (google for more about it). With steps moving on, it will lead you to the file (will be downloaded first) containing the class it runs.

Comment: I have noticed that you can click on classes, and it will navigate you directly to the definition. Thank God for strongly typed languages - I hope Microsoft keeps maintaining and developing these crucial tools for coherent, maintainable software.

Comment: actually that feature of github is not working perfectly, I mean it does not link to the correct references, instead it's much like finding the ***text*** only. So if the method has 3 overloads, it will show you 3 in the popup, not just exactly one as expected (like VS can do).

Comment: That is awesome about Source Link - I am definitely enabling that.  I downloaded the source code for ASPNetCore, opened it in VS, and am trying to build it now. I'll let you know when my computer becomes responsive again XD - I probably need the .NET 6 SDK. It also looks like the solution has NodeJS deps :( They just started pushing this new "Code Spaces" thing, and I have strong mixed emotions of excitement and fear about it.

Comment: with *Source Link*, you don't need to build the `asp.net core` source. Actually building the `asp.net core` source is fairly complicated, requiring many steps and ensured tools/sdks .. That way is not really necessary (although once built successfully, you will have better debugging experience).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230101/discussion-between-developer-dude-and-king-king).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know If I am understanding you correctly, you can config the login and access denied path in the startup file in the ConfigureServices method.

Example:

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
            // cookies 
            .AddCookie(options =>{
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/login";
            });
```

Comment: I do not want the query string: `ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FAccessDenied%3FReturnUrl%3D%252F` to be appended to the redirect path. It should either just be the page they just tried to load, or be blank.  I am short circuiting something in the system, and can not just use normal config to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to any page you want if you pass in a RedirectUri to SignOutAsync:

```
public async Task Signout()
{
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        RedirectUri = "/home/login"
    };

    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("cookie", props);
}
```